# Wrapping / bending text around a circle in plot

Tags: r, plot, text, graphics

Is there any chance to write text which is "wrapped" around the circle? I mean something like this:[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

##### `plotrix::arctext`

```
library(plotrix)

# set up a plot with a circle
plot(x = 0, y = 0, xlim = c(-2, 2), ylim = c(-2, 2))
draw.circle(x = 0, y = 0, radius = 1)

# add text
arctext(x = "wrap some text", center = c(0, 0), radius = 1.1, middle = pi/2)
arctext(x = "counterclockwise", center = c(0, 0), radius = 1.1, middle = 5*pi/4,
        clockwise = FALSE, cex = 1.5)
arctext(x = "smaller & stretched", center = c(0, 0), radius = 1.1, middle = 2*pi ,
        cex = 0.8, stretch = 1.2)
```

[image]

---

##### `circlize`

For greater opportunities of customization, check the `circlize` package (see [the `circlize` book](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/)). By setting `facing = "bending"` in `circos.text`, the text wraps around a circle.

```
library(circlize)

# create some angles, labels and their corresponding factors
# which determine the sectors 
deg <- seq(from = 0, to = 300, by = 60)
lab <- paste("some text", deg, "-", deg + 60)   
factors <- factor(lab, levels = lab)

# initialize plot
circos.par(gap.degree = 10)
circos.initialize(factors = factors, xlim = c(0, 1))
circos.trackPlotRegion(ylim = c(0, 1))

# add text to each sector  
lapply(factors, function(deg){
  circos.updatePlotRegion(sector.index = deg, bg.col = "red")
circos.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, labels = as.character(deg), facing = "bending")
})
circos.clear()
```

[image]

From [`circlize` version 0.2.1](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/NEWS), `circos.text` has two new options: `bending.inside` which is identical to original `bending` and `bending.outside` (see Figure 3.4 in [the `circlize` book](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/graphics.html#text)). Thus, it is easy to turn the text in the bottom half of the plot using `bending.outside`:

```
circos.par(gap.degree = 10)
circos.initialize(factors = factors, xlim = c(0, 1))
circos.trackPlotRegion(ylim = c(0, 1))

lapply(factors[1:3], function(deg){
  circos.updatePlotRegion(sector.index = deg, bg.col = "red")
  circos.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, labels = as.character(deg), facing = "bending.outside")
})

lapply(factors[4:6], function(deg){
  circos.updatePlotRegion(sector.index = deg, bg.col = "red")
  circos.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, labels = as.character(deg), facing = "bending.inside")
})
circos.clear()
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice because your `circlize` edit hit the nail on head.

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a while, but am I correct that this will not work with a general curve (like my `sin` example in my answer)?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, AFAIK, the functions I have used are developed for circles and not general curves like your nice example (+1!).

Comment: Thank you, package `circlize` is very useful. But it seems that text cannot be displayed in a way like using `plotrx`, I mean when `clockwise` is set to `FALSE` ('upside down'), am I wrong?

Answer (score 27):

Yes, and here is the code, free of charge :-) .  I wrote this a while back but I don't think ever published it in any CRAN package.

```
# Plot symbols oriented to local slope.
# Interesting problem: if underlying plot has some arbitrary aspect ratio,
# retrieve by doing: Josh O'B via SO:  
# myasp <- with(par(),(pin[2]/pin[1])/(diff(usr[3:4])/diff(usr[1:2])))
# so make that the default value of argument 'asp'
# Default is 'plotx' is vector of indices at which to 
# plot symbols.  If is_indices=FALSE, only then turn to splinefun to 
# calculate y-values and slopes; and user beware.
#
# 6 Feb 2014: added default col arg so can stick in a color vector if desired
# TODO
#
slopetext<-function(x,y,plotx, mytext, is_indices=TRUE, asp=with(par(), (pin[1]/pin[2])*(diff(usr[3:4])/diff(usr[1:2]))),offsetit= 0, col='black', ...) {
if (length(x) != length(y)) stop('data length mismatch')
if (!is.numeric(c(x,y,plotx) ) ) stop('data not numeric')
if(is_indices) {
    # plotting at existing points.
    if(any(plotx<=1) | any(plotx>= length(x))) {
        warning("can't plot endpoint; will remove")
        plotx<-plotx[(plotx>1 & plotx<length(x))]
    }
    lows<-plotx-1
    highs<-plotx+1
    # then interpolate low[j],high[j] to get slope at x2[j]
    slopes <- (y[highs]-y[lows])/(x[highs]-x[lows])  #local slopes
    # sign(highlow)  fix the rotation problem 
    angles <- 180/pi*atan(slopes/asp)  + 180*(x[lows] > x[highs] )
    intcpts <- y[highs]-slopes*x[highs]   
    ploty <- intcpts + x[plotx]*slopes
    # change name, so to speak, to simplify common plotting code
    plotx<-x[plotx]
    }else{
    #interpolating at plotx values
        if  (any(plotx<min(x)) | any(plotx>max(x)) ) {
            warning("can't plot extrapolated point; will remove")
            plotx<-plotx[(plotx>min(x) & plotx<max(x))]
        }
        spf<-splinefun(x,y)
        ploty<-spf(plotx)
        angles <- 180/pi * atan(spf(plotx,1)/asp) #getting first deriv, i.e. slope
    } #end of else
xlen<-length(plotx) # better match y and mytext
# The trouble is: srt rotates about some non-centered value in the text cell
# Dunno what to do about that.
dely <- offsetit*cos(angles)
delx <- offsetit*sin(angles)
# srt must be scalar
mytext<-rep(mytext,length=xlen)
col <- rep(col,length=xlen)
for (j in 1:xlen) text(plotx[j], ploty[j], labels=mytext[j], srt= angles[j], adj=c(delx,dely),col=col[j], ...)
}
```

Edit: per David's excellent suggestion, a sample case:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- x/20 + sin(x/10)
plot(x,y,t='l')
slopetext(x=x,y=y,plotx=seq(10,70,by=10),mytext=letters[1:8])
```

The third argument in this example selects every tenth value of (x,y) for placement of the text.
I should warn that I haven't idiot-proofed the `is_indices=FALSE` case and the spline fit may in extreme cases place your text in funny ways.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The figure in the question can now be recreated quite easily in ggplot using the `geomtextpath` package:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 5.5, 6, 5.2, 0, 0.5, 0) + 8 * rep(0:5, each = 7),
                 y = rep(c(0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0), 6) + 8,
                 id = rep(1:6, each = 7))

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(3, 11, 19, 27, 35, 43), y = 9, id = 1:6,
                  z = paste("text", 0:5 * 60))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = id)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = "red", color = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 9, color = "red", alpha = 0.3, size = 7) +
  geom_textpath(data = df2, aes(label = z), size = 7, upright = FALSE) +
  ylim(c(0, 10)) +
  xlim(c(0, 48)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1, start = -pi/4) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm co-author of said package.